# mixed action loss (custom) function in TensorFlow gives nan (NaN) at training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, loss-function

I am testing **custom** losses that combine classification and regression (YOLO's loss for example).
alas, TensorFlow gives nan (NaN) at training...
I've tried people's advice from here and anywhere but still, no fix.

here is my code:

```
def S_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    Gnoobj = 0.5
    Gcoord = 5.
    mask = y_pred[..., 0] > 0
    w_pred = tf.boolean_mask(y_pred[..., 1], mask)
    w_true = tf.boolean_mask(y_true[..., 1], mask)
    h_pred = tf.boolean_mask(y_pred[..., 2], mask)
    h_true = tf.boolean_mask(y_true[..., 2], mask)
    wmse = mean_squared_error(w_true, w_pred)
    hmse = mean_squared_error(h_true, h_pred)
    mse = wmse + hmse
    binary = binary_crossentropy(y_true[..., 0], y_pred[..., 0])
    return Gcoord * mse + Gnoobj * binary
```

thanks for any help!